# How to use same django backend for web and mobile?

Tags: django, reactjs, react-native, web

i have not a real problem but i have a question, i want to start learning mobile development, and i saw that you can make a mobile application with react and have a Django back-end, so, is possible to have a web application and a mobile application with the same Django back-end? how is it possible or which should use?
I have seen some videos about how to make a Django back-end for a mobile app, and for a web app too, but i don´t understand how to do both in the same back-end.
i would appreciate if you give me some tips, or another back-end framework to make it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expose the Django backend via HTTP API. Then consume that API from both your web ui, and mobile application.

This means you will essentially have 3 separate applications: mobile app, web app, api back end.

Both mobile app and web app can act as clients, and will ask the back end API whenever it needs to show or update details. The API backend will be accessed over the internet, like `GET api.example.com/api/user`

For example, you need to display user information in the Mobile App:

- Mobile app sends Http Get request to `api.example.com/api/user`
- api back end responds with user details, potentially in JSON format
- mobile app reads the JSON data and loads that into its UI

You need to display user information in the Web App:

- Web app sends Http Get request to `api.example.com/api/user`
- api back end responds with user details, potentially in JSON format
- Web app reads the JSON data and loads that into its UI

In both these use cases, you just reused the api back end to get user information. But have different views [mobile, web]

Comment: and both views can be wrote in react ?

Comment: Technically speaking, it does not matter what framework you use. But sure, you can use react if that's what you prefer.

Comment: I started searching what you said, i found that the most used for that is Django rest framework, is that right? would be like have in a Django project an Django-app for back-end API, another for web template, and a react-native or something to the mobile app?

Comment: Rest framework sounds about right. 
For web and mobile frameworks, I'd recommend starting off with what you are comfortable with.